# Add a domain user to the Administrator group of a WORKGROUP machine not joined to the domain?

Tags: domain, windows-8.1, workgroup

So I'm at a client and to connect to their SQL Server, I need to use SQL Server Windows Authentication.

The thing is that I do have a user that allowed me to connect to their TFS server without any problems. I've been trying to add a user of their domain to my Administrator groups and it doesn't seem to be able to do so.

I've tried through the GUI or through the command line (net localgroup Administrators....).

No chance so far.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you guys were right. Impossible to grant rights to a user outside of your own workgroup/domain. However, I found a workaround.

Since I needed to start SQL Server (aka: ssms.exe), I've found that I can start a process as another user like so:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\user /netonly ssms.exe
```

And it runs without problem SQL Server with Windows Authentication.

My source: https://superuser.com/questions/30508/temporarily-login-to-another-windows-domain

Comment: +1 - `runas` w/ the `/netonly` argument is an under-appreciated tool. It certainly makes my life easier, carting around a laptop that isn't joined to any of my Custmers' domains but sometimes need to manage SQL Server or Hyper-V instances on their domains.

Answer (score 6):

No, that is not possible.

If you create a local account with the same username+password, that should work for many activities.  It's fairly easy to setup and test, so you may want to try that.